# Wordpress - Unable to call woocommerce filter

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

I'm having an issue when try to apply a filter to `woocommerce_package_rates`.

**Basically what I'm trying to do, is hide some shipping methods if a coupon code is applied.**

This is my test code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'display_coupon');
function display_coupon($order)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    global $wpdb;
    if (isset($_POST['coupon_code'])) {
        add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_coupon_code_is_available', 10, 2); 
        echo "Ok"
       } else {
        echo "no"
        }
}

function hide_shipping_when_coupon_code_is_available($rates, $package){
    $test= $rates['table_rate_shipping_test'];
    $rates = array();
    $rates['test'] = $test;
    return $rates;
}
```

Now, When I apply the coupon code, the variable `$coupon_code` is populated and it goes inside the if statement, but it doesn't seam to call the `woocommerce_package_rates` filter. Is it wrong try to call a filter from inside another function like that? if no, what else am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

PS: As a reference, I modified this code here -> http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
add_action('wp', 'wdm_my_custom_function');

function wdm_my_custom_function() {

    global $woocommerce;
    global $wpdb;
    if ( isset($_POST['coupon_code']) ) {
    add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_coupon_code_is_available', 10, 2);
    echo "Ok";
    } else {
    echo "no";
    }
}
```

Let me know if your problem is solved by this.